# 100vh Vimeo Player iframe

Tags: css, vue.js, vimeo-player

i am embedding a Vimeo video and ran into some issues styling the thing.
This is the player I use: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk
The player should fill the screen entirely for every viewport-size, hence `min-width: 100vh` and `min-height: 100vw`.

I managed to make the player fit the width, using

```
  ::v-deep iframe {
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vw;

    .player {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

  }
```

However, it ignores the min-height. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Edit:
The code I have so far is the following:

```css
body {
background-color: yellow;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.container {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 overflow: hidden; 
}
iframe {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vw;
}

.player {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
   <iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you  put an example in your question - at the moment I can't quite understand what you mean by the player filling the viewport as they may have different aspect ratios.

Comment: I can't provide an example because I can't get it to work. What I mean is that the entire window is always covered by the video.  if the window aspect ratio is different from the video aspect radio the video will be cut off.

Comment: OK, so it sounds you want it to behave like cover would on background-size or object-fit. You say that you managed to make the player fit the width, so that would be a good example of the code to put in the question and we can take it from there.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddel: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ev5AkOjwVG 
Basically, I would like to not see the yellow area at all times.

Comment: Your link appears to be just taking me to collaborative jsfiddle. Please could you put your example up in a Stackoverflow snippet in your question, not in an external service. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry., something went wrong there. I updated my post with a stackoverflow snippet

Answer (score 4):

If the viewport is narrow (that is, its aspect ratio is less than the aspect ratio of the video) then it is required that the video take up the full height of the viewport and the bits that then make it too wide are cropped. In this snippet it is assumed that in this scenario the video should be centered horizontally.

Converseley, if the viewport is too wide, the video should take up the full width of the viewport and it should be cropped top and bottom.

This snippet uses a simple container to hold the video, and an inbuilt video aspect ratio. This aspect ratio should be changed to match whatever video is to be played (or Javascript used to find out what it is at load time and the CSS variable --videoRatio altered accordingly). It calculates the required height and width in terms of the relative aspect ratios of the device and the video.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
     --videoRatio: calc(16 / 9); /* CHANGE THIS IF THE VIDEO CHANGES */
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }
    /* to start with assume that the viewport is wide enough for the video taking up full width the height will be at least 100vh */
iframe {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    --w: 100vw;
    --h: calc(var(--w) / var(--videoRatio));
    height: var(--h);
    width: var(--w);
    top: calc(50% - (var(--h) / 2));
    left: 0;
    width: var(--w);
    height: var(--h);
}
    /* Maximum aspect ratio */
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {/*the viewport is too narrow for the full video */
  iframe {
    --h: 100vh;
    --w: calc(var(--h) * var(--videoRatio));
    top: 0;
    left: calc(50% - (var(--w) / 2));
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
       <iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```