# How do i remove the white spaces surrounding my video and stretch it to fill the whole thing?

Tags: html, css, video

Can someone tell me how to remove all the white spaces surrounding the video. I want to stretch the video until the end and fill the whole container. I tried removing the padding & margin but it doesn't seem to work, i'm not sure why either. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav__bar {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

header .logo {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 80px;
}

header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-left: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.content .textBox {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.content .textBox h2 {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.content .textBox h2 span {
    color: #017143;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.content .textBox p {
    color: #333;
}

.content .textBox a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background: #017143;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content .imgBox {
    width: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.content .imgBox img {
    max-width: 340px;
}

.thumb {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 20px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
}

.thumb li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.thumb li:hover {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.thumb li img {
    max-width: 60px;
}

.sci {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 30px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sci li {
    list-style: none;
}

.sci li a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transform: scale(0.6);
    filter: invert(1);
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #017143;
    clip-path: circle(600px at right 800px);
}

.footer-dark {
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #f0f9ff;
    background-color: #282d32;
}

.footer-dark h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.footer-dark ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer-dark ul a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.footer-dark ul a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .footer-dark .item:not(.social) {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

.footer-dark .item.text {
    margin-bottom: 36px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .footer-dark .item.text {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

.footer-dark .item.text p {
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer-dark .item.social {
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
    .footer-dark .item.social {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}

.footer-dark .item.social>a {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    margin: 0 8px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.footer-dark .item.social>a:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.footer-dark .copyright {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 24px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.video {
    padding-bottom: 0!important;
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
    padding-top: 0!important;
    margin-top: 0!important;
    padding-right: 0;
    object-fit: fill;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <title>Starbucks</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <header>
            <a href="#"><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>
            <ul class="nav__bar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="textBox">
                <h2>It's not just Coffee<br>It's <span>Starbucks</span></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, suscipit! Ut quos maiores doloremque delectus reiciendis optio assumenda esse consequuntur voluptates! Porro impedit cumque asperiores iste nam est maxime tempore, ducimus,
                    vitae ipsum rerum, necessitatibus fugit.</p>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img src="/images/img1.png" class="starbucks">
            </div>
        </div>


        <ul class="thumb">
            <li><img src="/images/thumb1.png" onclick="imgSlider('/images/img1.png');changeCircleColor('#017143')"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/thumb2.png" onclick="imgSlider('/images/img2.png');changeCircleColor('#eb7495')"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/thumb3.png" onclick="imgSlider('/images/img3.png');changeCircleColor('#d752b1')"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="sci">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="/images/facebook.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="/images/twitter.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="/images/instagram.png"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="video">
        <video autoplay muted loop src="/images/coffee.mp4"></video>
    </section>


    <div class="footer-dark">
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">
                        <h3>Services</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Web design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">
                        <h3>About</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 item text">
                        <h3>Company Name</h3>
                        <p>Praesent sed lobortis mi. Suspendisse vel placerat ligula. Vivamus ac sem lacus. Ut vehicula rhoncus elementum. Etiam quis tristique lectus. Aliquam in arcu eget velit pulvinar dictum vel in justo.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col item social"><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-snapchat"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-instagram"></i></a></div>
                </div>
                <p class="copyright">Company Name © 2018</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        function imgSlider(anything) {
            document.querySelector('.starbucks').src = anything;
        }

        function changeCircleColor(color) {
            const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
            circle.style.background = color;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w2l4.jpg)

Comment: Assuming you don't want to distort the video, i.e. you want it to be shown like an object with cover - bits cut off at the bottom/top or sides as required, then [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67608597/100vh-vimeo-player-iframe/67623758#67623758 should help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to add min-height, min-width, and position property to the video element and overflow property to its parent element.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/vy2j84uw/1/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__bar {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

header .logo {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80px;
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

header ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.content .textBox {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.content .textBox h2 {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content .textBox h2 span {
  color: #017143;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.content .textBox p {
  color: #333;
}

.content .textBox a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background: #017143;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content .imgBox {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.content .imgBox img {
  max-width: 340px;
}

.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.thumb li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.thumb li:hover {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.thumb li img {
  max-width: 60px;
}

.sci {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sci li {
  list-style: none;
}

.sci li a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  filter: invert(1);
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #017143;
  clip-path: circle(600px at right 800px);
}

.footer-dark {
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: #f0f9ff;
  background-color: #282d32;
}

.footer-dark h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.footer-dark ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer-dark ul a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.footer-dark ul a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .footer-dark .item:not(.social) {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

.footer-dark .item.text {
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .footer-dark .item.text {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.footer-dark .item.text p {
  opacity: 0.6;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer-dark .item.social {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  .footer-dark .item.social {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

.footer-dark .item.social>a {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  margin: 0 8px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.footer-dark .item.social>a:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.footer-dark .copyright {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 24px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.video {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0;
  object-fit: fill;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <title>Starbucks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <header>
      <a href="#"><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>
      <ul class="nav__bar">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="textBox">
        <h2>It's not just Coffee<br>It's <span>Starbucks</span></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, suscipit! Ut quos maiores doloremque delectus reiciendis optio assumenda esse consequuntur voluptates! Porro impedit cumque asperiores iste nam est maxime tempore, ducimus, vitae
          ipsum rerum, necessitatibus fugit.</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="imgBox">
        <img src="/images/img1.png" class="starbucks">
      </div>
    </div>


    <ul class="thumb">
      <li><img src="/images/thumb1.png" onclick="imgSlider('/images/img1.png');changeCircleColor('#017143')"></li>
      <li><img src="/images/thumb2.png" onclick="imgSlider('/images/img2.png');changeCircleColor('#eb7495')"></li>
      <li><img src="/images/thumb3.png" onclick="imgSlider('/images/img3.png');changeCircleColor('#d752b1')"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sci">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/facebook.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/twitter.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/instagram.png"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section class="video">
    <video autoplay muted loop src="https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4"></video>
  </section>


  <div class="footer-dark">
    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">
            <h3>Services</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Web design</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">
            <h3>About</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 item text">
            <h3>Company Name</h3>
            <p>Praesent sed lobortis mi. Suspendisse vel placerat ligula. Vivamus ac sem lacus. Ut vehicula rhoncus elementum. Etiam quis tristique lectus. Aliquam in arcu eget velit pulvinar dictum vel in justo.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col item social"><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-snapchat"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-instagram"></i></a></div>
        </div>
        <p class="copyright">Company Name © 2018</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




  <script type="text/javascript">
    function imgSlider(anything) {
      document.querySelector('.starbucks').src = anything;
    }

    function changeCircleColor(color) {
      const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
      circle.style.background = color;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Btw, how can i reduce the height of the video?